# Не срабатывает функция при выборе <option> - ов в <datalist>

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {

    var Step = $('input[name="Step"]'),
      Result = $('input[name="Result"]'),
      Granite = 2500,
      Marble = 1700,
      Onyx = 5500,
      Travertine = 2300,
      Limestone = 4600;

    $('#Calculation-step__one-close').on('click', function() {
      $('.Calculation-step__one').css('display', 'none');
      $('.Calculation-step__two').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('#Type-of-stone').change(function() { // Пробовал исп-ть .on('click', function() {......
      if ($('#Type-of-stone option:selected').val() == Гранит) { //Вот 
        //тут уже ничего не происходит
        Step.on('input', function() {
          Result.val(($(this).val() * Granite) + Рублей);
        });
      }
      if ($('#Type-of-stone option:selected').val() == Мрамор) {
        Step.on('input', function() {
          Result.val(($(this).val() * Marble) + ' Рублей');
        });
      }
      if ($('#Type-of-stone option:selected').val() == Оникс) {
        Step.on('input', function() {
          Result.val(($(this).val() * Onyx) + ' Рублей');
        });
      }
      if ($('#Type-of-stone option:selected').val() == Травертин) {
        Step.on('input', function() {
          Result.val(($(this).val() * Travertine) + ' Рублей');
        });
      }
      if ($('#Type-of-stone option:selected').val() == Известняк) {
        Step.on('input', function() {
          Result.val(($(this).val() * Limestone) + ' Рублей');
        });
      }

    });


    $('#Calculation-step__two-close').on('click', function() {
      $('.Calculation-step__two').css('display', 'none');
      $('.Calculation-step__result').css('display', 'block');
    });


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Calculation-step__one">
  <h6>Введите площадь отделки</h6>
  <input type="text" id="Step__one" name="Step" value="площадь отделки, м2">
  <button id="Calculation-step__one-close">Далее</button>
  <br>
  <small>шаг 1 из 3</small>
</div>
<div class="Calculation-step__two">
  <h6>Выберете тип камня</h6>
  <input class="Calculation-step__list" list="Type-of-stone" name="Type-of-stone" required>
  <datalist id="Type-of-stone">
                      <option id="Granite-cost" value="Гранит">
                      <option id="Marble-cost" value="Мрамор">
                      <option id="Onyx-cost" value="Оникс">
                      <option id="Travertine-cost" value="Травертин">
                      <option id="Limestone-cost" value="Известняк">
                      </datalist>
  <button id="Calculation-step__two-close">Далее</button>
  <br>
  <small>шаг 2 из 3</small>
</div>
<div class="Calculation-step__result">
  <h6>Примерная стоимость</h6>
  <input type="text" id="Result" name="Result" value="Руб">
  <br>
  <small>шаг 3 из 3</small>
</div>
```

На выходе в классе `.Calculation-step__result` ничего не выводиться просто. Как сделать так что бы при выборе определенного `option-a` выводилось произведение одного из `var-ov` ( Granite, Marble, Onyx, Travertine,Limestone) * ввод числа в `input-е` с класcом `.Сalculation-step__one`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ох и намудрили Вы с разметкой и скриптами - море лишних атрибутов. Попробовал чуть сократить и оптимизировать:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    var Step = $('input[name="Step"]'),
      Stone = $('input[name="Type-of-stone"]'),
      Result = $('input[name="Result"]');
    var aPrices = {
      'Гранит': 2500,
      'Мрамор': 1700,
      'Оникс': 5500,
      'Травертин': 2300,
      'Известняк': 4600
    }
    
    $('input[name="Type-of-stone"]').on('input change', function() {
      let nSquare = parseFloat(Step.val()) || 0;
      Result.val(nSquare * aPrices[$(this).val()] + ' Рублей');
    });
    
    $('#Calculation-step__one-close').on('click', function() {
      if (Number.isNaN(parseFloat(Step.val()))) { alert('Укажите площадь'); Step.focus(); return }
      $('.Calculation-step__one').css('display', 'none');
      $('.Calculation-step__two').css('display', 'block');
    });
    
    $('#Calculation-step__two-close').on('click', function() {
      if (aPrices[Stone.val()] === undefined) { alert('Укажите тип камня'); Stone.val(''); Stone.focus(); return }
      $('.Calculation-step__two').css('display', 'none');
      $('.Calculation-step__result').css('display', 'block');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.Calculation-step__two, .Calculation-step__result { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Calculation-step__one">
  <h6>Введите площадь отделки</h6>
  <input type="text" id="Step__one" name="Step" value="" placeholder="площадь отделки, м²">
  <button id="Calculation-step__one-close">Далее</button>
  <br>
  <small>шаг 1 из 3</small>
</div>
<div class="Calculation-step__two">
  <h6>Выберете тип камня</h6>
  <input class="Calculation-step__list" list="Type-of-stone" name="Type-of-stone" value="" placeholder="тип камня" required>
  <datalist id="Type-of-stone">
    <option value="Гранит">
    <option value="Мрамор">
    <option value="Оникс">
    <option value="Травертин">
    <option value="Известняк">
  </datalist>
  <button id="Calculation-step__two-close">Далее</button>
  <br>
  <small>шаг 2 из 3</small>
</div>
<div class="Calculation-step__result">
  <h6>Примерная стоимость</h6>
  <input type="text" id="Result" name="Result" value="" placeholder="стоимость, руб.">
  <br>
  <small>шаг 3 из 3</small>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!) Действительно заработало!) Вопрос к вам еще один: уже практически неделю колупаю JQuery, ставлю себе задачи и пытаюсь их решить...Как  понять в какую сторону колупать и где и как искать решение???Никогда бы до такого не додумался до такого решения...(( Как понять куда надо копать при решении той или иной задачи???)

Comment: @101 рекомендую пересмотреть подход к заданию атрибутов и названиям классов. Удачи!